# JIB is generating image with outdated state of the project

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, podman, jib

I'm developing a Java Quarkus microservice. I want to build my image using JIB and push the resulting image to my local registry that i have running in podman. This is how if have setup the JIB plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jib-quarkus-extension-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>0.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>localhost:5000/jdk21</image>
                    </from>
                    <to>
                        <image>localhost:5000/myimage2</image>
                        <tags>
                            <!-- <tag>latest</tag> -->
                            <!-- <tag>${project.version}</tag> -->
                            <tag>0.0.0.1</tag>
                        </tags>
                    </to>
                    <container>
                        <mainClass>bogus</mainClass>
                        <jvmFlags>
                            <flag>-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0</flag>
                            <flag>-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</flag>
                        </jvmFlags>
                        <ports>
                            <port>8080</port>
                        </ports>
                        <user>1001</user>
                    </container>
                    <pluginExtensions>
                        <pluginExtension>
                            <implementation>com.google.cloud.tools.jib.maven.extension.quarkus.JibQuarkusExtension</implementation>
                            <properties>
                                <packageType>fast-jar</packageType>
                            </properties>
                        </pluginExtension>
                    </pluginExtensions>
                    <allowInsecureRegistries>true</allowInsecureRegistries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I'm also pulling the JDK from my local repository. The initial image generation was successful and properly runs in podman.

I run `mvn compile jib:build` to start the generation process.
I have made changes to the application.properties config file and the resulting image got pushed to the registry, but the image is still using the state of the project. I have tried to specifically set tags and run those tags explicitely, no change. I have also tried to push the image to a new repository in my registry, but still no change.

However, when I run `mvn install` and run the resulting .jar normally, the changes to the config are correct and my new rest endpoint is available.

Using Dockerfile and creating image using the Docker Daemon is not an option.

Comment: The problem description makes me think that either `mvn compile` is not enough for a Quarkus project, or (more likely) your Maven project/JIB plugin is misconfigured so that the configuration files simply don't get into the final jar. Please add more specific details of your configuration (i.e. whether it is a multi-module project, or whether the configuration options could be inherited from somewhere, or why are you using `mvn compile` for JIB but `mvn install` for running a jar). By the way, Podman is also able to build the images, you don't need Docker for that.